# Maps Api UI elements appear very large (larger then the map itself)

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to use the [HERE Maps Api](https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api) in my website.
I'm making a Web Component/custom element for maps but I'm running into issues with the UI.

1.
in my code I have the lines

```
this.defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
this.ui = Maps.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, this.defaultLayers, 'de-DE');
```

but, no controls show up on the map, nothing
BUT, I do see a large plus for a second that then disappears.

2.I tried adding a bubble

```
var bubble = new Maps.ui.InfoBubble({ lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }, {
    content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
});
this.ui.addBubble(bubble);
```

well, the bubble made the plus not appear for a second but it also made a GIANT x on the map, an X which is supposed to be about 15x15 pixels.

I even tried doing [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js) example, copied it from their website, it had the same sorts of UI problems.
I thought that maybe the problem is that I'm using the es6 module version instead of the standard version (that you add with script tags)
nope, using the standard version did not change anything.

[here is a repo showing what I'm doing](https://github.com/GideonMax/test-server)
the repo's readme file will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Can you please help with the console logs ? Are the credentials correct ? can you also try changing browser ?

Comment: 1. the credentials are correct, or else other things wouldn't have worked.

2. I tried changing browsers, didn't help.

3. I'm not sure what you mean, I have tried logging basically everything (on my own personal project as I don't want to clutter the repo) and it doesn't help, what do you want me to log?
I suggest you try to run the server in the repo I provided and see what I mean